# Office 365 Powershell Empty Deleted Items folder

Tags: powershell, office365

We currently use Office 365 in the office and I would like to delete all emails from Deleted items folder for a specific users.

I've tried using following command, but it doesn't appear to delete emails in Deleted Items folder

```
Search-Mailbox "Mailbox.Name" -SearchDumpsterOnly -DeleteContent
```

Is there any other way to do it?

PS. I have found references on how to do this with cmdlets that no longer exist [export-mailbox for example].

Answer (score 0):

O365 notwithstanding as the same thing would apply to Exchange on-premises.

Search for and delete messages in Exchange 2016
Learn how to search for and purge messages from Exchange 2016 mailboxes.
You can use the New-ComplianceSearch and New-ComplianceSearchAction cmdlets to search for and delete an email message from all mailboxes in your organization. This can help you find and remove potentially harmful or high-risk email, such as:

```
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459253(v=exchg.160).aspx
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-for-and-delete-email-messages-in-your-Office-365-organization-Admin-Help-3526fd06-b45f-445b-aed4-5ebd37b3762a
```

The SearchDumpster = Search recoverable items (Emails that were deleted from the Trash), not the deleted folder.
AS specifically defined in the Exchange cmdlet online help...

**-SearchDumpster** 
The SearchDumpster parameter specifies whether to search the Recoverable Items folder, which is the storage location in which items deleted from the Deleted Items folder or hard-deleted items are stored until they're purged from the mailbox database.

**-SearchDumpsterOnly** 
The SearchDumpsterOnly switch specifies that only the Recoverable Items folder of the specified mailbox be searched. You can also use this switch with the DeleteContent switch to delete messages from the Recoverable Items folder and reduce the size of the folder.

If you are just trying to clear mail because of mail quota issues. Rather than doing this with PoSH, it would be better for you to set a retention policy on the Deleted or other folder as needed to purge content.

The other approach is use the Search cmdlet, to target a folder by date range and delete those.

Your other option is to write a bit more code and use the EWS API to delete items. 
Deleting items by using EWS in Exchange
Find out how you can use the EWS Managed API or EWS in Exchange to delete items either by moving them to the Deleted Items folder or to the dumpster.
Have you ever asked yourself what the difference is between moving items to the Deleted Items folder, and moving them to the dumpster? You might be curious about the different options for handling deleted items and how to implement those options in your application. Exchange Web Services (EWS) includes three options for handling deleted items. This article will hopefully clear up any confusion you might have about the differences between them.

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn424760(v=exchg.150).aspx
```